# Case insensitive Query with Spring CrudRepository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

With Spring CrudRepository Query; I want to select "DeviceType" entities with it's "name" property. But following query select the entitles on case sensitive manner. How I make it case insensitive way. Thanks.

```
public interface DeviceTypeRepository extends CrudRepository<DeviceType, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<DeviceType> {

    public Iterable<DeviceType> findByNameContaining(String name);

}
```

Comment: Did you try `public Iterable<DeviceType> findByNameIgnoreCaseContaining(String name);`?

Comment: In case if you interested in Query then please try this, No need to give '%' after LIKE                                                                      
    <code> @Query(value= "select dt from DeviceType as dt where lower(dt.name) like lower(:name)")                                                                                  
       public Iterable<DeviceType> anyMethodNameGoesHere(@Param(name) String name);</code>

Comment: This may help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178520/jpql-like-case-insensitive/62988377#62988377

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Exactly as @Peter mentioned in the comment, just add `IgnoreCase`:

```
public interface DeviceTypeRepository 
    extends CrudRepository<DeviceType, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<DeviceType> {

    public Iterable<DeviceType> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);
}
```

See [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for a list of all supported keywords inside method names.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer; sure I will refer that documentation. May Thanks. Have a great time !

Comment: It worked for me. I was using JPA query. So as per the documentation, where UPPER(x.firstame) = UPPER(?1) worked.

Comment: @sunitha do you know of any way we could modify this behaviour, say make it LOWER? My db has indexing based on lower case

Comment: @SudipBhandari : Sure u can.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171569/spring-with-crudrepository-and-ignorecase

Comment: For multiple properties repead `IgnoreCase` like this: `List<Account> findByUsernameIgnoreCaseAndDomainIgnoreCase(String username, String domain);`

Comment: remember to extend the interface _JpaSpecificationExecutor_ in your repository

Comment: does this apply to all parameters or only for the one after which it is specified. For example if I wanted to find by first name and last name both case insensitive, would i do findByFirstNameIgnoreCaseAndLastNameIgnoreCase or findByFirstNameAndLastNameIgnoreCase ?

Comment: Roadrunner, @sunitha Can i use this method name with pageable as second param, will it work ?

Comment: `findByNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByNameAsc` in finde by name containing + ignore case + order by column name ascending

Answer (score 13):

The following Spring data mongo query works for me. I would prefer to use `List` instead of `Iterator`

```
public interface DeviceTypeRepository extends CrudRepository<DeviceType,Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<DeviceType> {
    List<DeviceType> findByNameIgnoreCase(String name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case adding `IgnoreCase` did not work at all.

I found that it is possible to provide options for the regular expression ,as well:

```
@Query(value = "{'title': {$regex : ?0, $options: 'i'}}")
Foo findByTitleRegex(String regexString);
```

The `i` option makes the query case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

For those who uses custom JPA query **Upper** keyword and **toUpperCase** helps. The following code works for me

```
 return  entityManager.createQuery("select q from "table " q  where upper(q.applicant)=:applicant")
    .setParameter("applicant",applicant.toUpperCase().trim()).getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Be carefull when use 'upper(q.applicant)'. In Postgres it causes '.PSQLException: ERROR: function upper(bytea) does not exist' when q.applicant is null

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding `IgnoreCase` work like this. i would prefer to use `list` instead of  `iterator`

```
public List<ContactEntity> findByNameIgnoreCaseContainingAndUserEntity(String name, UserEntity userEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

While, I think, answers already provided bring some bits of useful information, I also think that they are lacking.

Spring Data JPA's query building/generation mechanism parses the names of methods that are explicitly (by developer) declared in the custom repository interfaces (which extend `CrudRepository<T, ID>` or any of its subtypes) and based on those names, it generates native queries for the corresponding backing datastore/database.

Let's say, we have an managed type (i.e. @Entity) `Person`, as follows:

```java
class Person {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Integer age;
    
    //getters, setters, constructor, etc.
}
```

and a corresponding repository, that works with this entity:

```java
interface PersonRepository<Person, Integer> {
}
```

In order to instruct Spring Data JPA to ignore the case of values provided as arguments to the user-declared repository methods, you can use:

1. `IgnoreCase` - for ignoring case-sensitivity of the specific field; or
2. `AllIgnoreCase` - for ignoring case-sensitivity of all the fields.

Note, that while you should be placing `IgnoreCase` right after the field you want to ignore case-sensitivity for, you can place `AllIgnoreCase` in almost any place of a method name that you declare.

### Ignore case-sensitivity for the specific fields/columns:

Ignores the case of `firstname` and `lastname` values:

```java
List<Person> findByFirstnameIgnoreCaseAndLastnameIgnoreCase(String firstname, String lastname);
```

Ignores the case of `lastname` value:

```java
List<Person> findByFirstnameAndLastnameIgnoreCase(String firstname, String lastname);
```

Ignores the case of `firstname` value:

```java
List<Person> findByFirstnameIgnoreCaseAndLastname(String firstname, String lastname);
```

### Ignore case-sensitivity for all the fields/columns:

Placing `AllIgnoreCase` right before any parameter name:

```java
List<Person> findByAllIgnoreCaseFirstnameAndLastname(String firstname, String lastname);
```

or after only some parameter name:

```java
List<Person> findByFirstnameAllIgnoreCaseAndLastname(String firstname, String lastname);
```

or in the end, after all the parameter names:

```java
List<Person> findByFirstnameAndLastnameAllIgnoreCase(String firstname, String lastname);
```

or even in the very beginning, swapping `findBy` with it:

```java
List<Person> AllIgnoreCaseFirstnameAndLastname(String firstname, String lastname);
```

would all result in the same behaviour - ignoring case-sensitivity for all the fields/columns when generating query.