# JPA findBy field ignore case

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, dao

How do I make findByIn search using IgnoreCase of `<Field>`? 
I tried to use `findByNameIgnoreCaseIn` and `findByNameInIgnoreCase` with no result.
DB is Postgresql.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository {
    List<User> findByNameIgnoreCaseIn(List<String> userNames);
}
```

Comment: @v.ladynev it's a spring data repository where programmer don't have to provide the implementation.

Comment: I suppose Spring data/jpa **IgnoreCase** keyword does not work with **In** Keyword.

Comment: make your own implementation...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive Query with Spring CrudRepository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573428/case-insensitive-query-with-spring-crudrepository)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I understood IgnoreCase is not supported with In key, so I changed code this way:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository {
    @Query("select user from SysUser user where upper(name) in :userNames")
    List<SysUser> findByNameIgnoreCaseIn(@Param("userNames") List<String> userNames);
}
```

and previously upper case userNames values.

Answer (score 21):

Try something like this:

```
List<User> findByNameInIgnoreCase(List<String> userNames);
```

Comment: this worked for me. put in the IN before the ignorecase