# findBy method query in Spring Boot does not work in a case sensitive manner

Tags: spring-boot

I have been through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573428/case-insensitive-query-with-spring-crudrepository). From that I infer, findBy queries are **Case Sensitive** and you can add `IgnoreCase` for the case insensitive behavior.

I have created a login controller where I am checking if the user credentials are correct or not using findBy query.

```
myUserDao.findByLoginIdAndPassword(loginId, password);
```

I am testing this using a Rest Client.

The user present in the DB has loginId as `testuser` and a encrypted password `a12f4ae0cd227501191616c77ac0a234`.

Now when I enter the user as `Testuser` and password as `a12f4ae0cd227501191616c77ac0a234` the user is still able to login. The find by query returns successfully with a MyUser Entity even though the username entered has a different case.

=================

EDIT 1: Code for Login

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> loginUser(@RequestBody Map<String, String> rawpayload) {

        String loginId = null;
        String password = null;

        try {
            loginId = rawpayload.get("loginId");
            password = rawpayload.get("password");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("",e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please check your payload format.");
        }

        MyUser myUser = myUserDao.findByLoginIdAndPassword(loginId, password);

        if (myUser == null) {
            logger.error("Invalid login ID(" + loginId + ") and password.");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                    .body(CommonUtils.createErrorResponseMessage("Invalid loginId or password."));
        }

    }

    logger.info("User '" + loginId + "' logged in successfully.");
    return jsonUtils.getJsonForResponse(myUser);
}
```

Comment: Then I doubt that your check is actually correct. Also which database are you using (some are case insensitive by default!) and show the code you use to check the passwords/usernames.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using MySql.  I have updated the question with the code

Comment: Which is case insensitive by default. Also why are you doing a query with password? Client should send plain password, you should check which you should encrypt and then check the values. (Also instead of rolling your own, I suggest using Spring Security instead).